# Find A Cell In Sheet1 Then Copy The Entire Row That It Is In To The First Empty Row in Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a "subscript out of range" at the line starting:  Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells("A", i).EntireRow.Copy . How do I copy and paste the row to the first open row in Sheet2.

```
Sub IDwalkups()
Dim endRow As Long
Dim Match1() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ICount = 0
endRow = Sheet1.Range("B999999").End(xlUp).Row

Match1 = Sheet1.Range("E3:E" & endRow)
For i = LBound(Match1) To UBound(Match1)
    If Match1(i, 1) = "W" Then

    Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells("A", i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets   (“Sheet2”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    Else
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three errors you have are:

- using `“` and `”` instead of `"`.  For instance, `“Sheet1”` is a valid **variable name** and can be used in statements such as `“Sheet1” = 5 * 2`.  Syntactically, it is quite different to `"Sheet1"` which is a string literal.
- Using `Cells("A", i)` instead of `Cells(i, "A")` - the first parameter of `Cells` is the row, and the second parameter is the column.
- Not qualifying which sheet you are referring to when using `Rows.Count` (but there is a good chance that this would have worked anyway)

So

```
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells("A", i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets   (“Sheet2”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

should have been

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 errors.
First the Copy & Paste are two steps (2 commands). Second, if you use `Cells`, you have to give row and column as Number-Parameter. You have to change it to `Range`.

```
    If Match1(i, 1) = "W" Then
        Dim sourceRange As Range, destRange As Range
        Set sourceRange = ws.Range("A" & i).EntireRow
        ' or Set sourceRange = ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
        sourceRange.Copy
        Set destRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        destRange.PasteSpecial
    End If
```

Comment: `Cells("A", i)` is incorrect, but `Cells(i, "A")` would be OK - the column doesn't need to be numeric, it can be a string

Comment: Hey YowE3K, I'm using VBA since years and use `.Cells` all the time, but never realized that.

Comment: I only learnt that when I started hanging around SO about 10 months ago, and I think I have been using VBA since it first came out!

Comment: Oh - Copy/Paste don't have to be two operations - what the OP did is fine, so the two errors are the incorrect quotation marks, and the row/column switch in `Cells`

Comment: @FunThomas  both your answer works. Thank you your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @YowE3K your answer also works and is the solution I went with. Thank you your help is much appreciated.