# Generating an array, and using Vlookup to loop through this array (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, function, vlookup

using the following code i have tried to generate an array based on what is in column "LN", (all values in "LN" are named ranges, corresponding to different cells). Then using vlookup I want it to look at cell d25, and look for a match within every named range of the array.

```
Sub Find_Value()

Sheets(“Sheet5”).Select

Dim arr() As Variant

arr() = Sheets("Sheet5").Range("LN4:LN" & LRow).Value

Dim I As Long
For I = 1 To Range("LN").End(xlUp).Value

Sheets(“Estimation - Entry”).Select
Range("P40").Value = arr(1)  
Range(“E25").Value=WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range(“D25").Value,Range((arr(i)),2,0)
End Sub
```

(this code doesn't work and i am unsure why)

Comment: remove the `On Error Resume Next` and run the code, then tell us on which line it gets an error and what that error is.

Comment: Also `arr() = Range("LN4").End(xlUp).Value` is creating an array with only one cell's value.

Comment: it says syntax error, for the following:"Range(“E25").Value=WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range(“D25").Value,Range(arr(i)),2,0)"

Comment: also how would i get it to create an array of all values in that column?

Comment: I have changed the above code, to fix the array that I have created, however it is still not working

Comment: Is that code copy/pasted from VBE into the question?  If so, have you declared variables `“Sheet5”`, `“Estimation`, and `Entry”`?  Also, you have a syntax error - the string literal `").Value=WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range(“D25"` cannot immediately follow the variable `“E25` - you need an operator of some sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find A Cell In Sheet1 Then Copy The Entire Row That It Is In To The First Empty Row in Sheet2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066318/find-a-cell-in-sheet1-then-copy-the-entire-row-that-it-is-in-to-the-first-empty)

Comment: And just in case my comment and suggested duplicate are too subtle - do **not** use `“` and `”` instead of `"`. `“Sheet5”` is a variable name, just like your variable names `I` and `arr`, but `"Sheet5"` is a string literal.

Comment: Thanks, the code now runs. However it still does not work. I think It is that the array is not being set properly. (I have tried to make the code set cell "P40" to be equal to the array, so i can see what it is generating but nothing appears in that cell when the code runs, suggesting it is not working... but i am unsure why this as happened)

Comment: `arr` is a two-dimensional array - if you want the first "row" and first "column" from that array you need to use `arr(1,1)`.  (Note: You have never set `LRow`, so I am surprised it didn't crash trying to assign that array to be the values in cells in `LN0:LN4` - `LN0` is not a valid cell.)

Comment: Oh, i thought LRow, looks for the lowest row of that column that has something in? I was just looking for it to make an array of everything that was in that column